# Issues ragarding parsing of xml data to HL7 in java?

Tags: java, hl7

I have an application where i used the HL7 encoding and decoding concept. I am able to encode simple string to HL7 message and also able to decode the HL7 message to XML format. But I want to convert xml file data to the HL7 message.

Can any one help me how i do this and also give the some reference where i get some help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **hapi** perser api for this. Please refer :  http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/parsing.html

Comment: I am not asking that. I am asking how to convert xml data to HL7 message.

Answer (score 0):

HAPI is able to convert HL7 2.x messages back and forth between the two standard encodings: ER7 (vertical bar format) and XML. If you're asking how to convert some other type of XML data into an HL7 message then that's going to depend on the schema.